# Passing multiple variables using laravel controller function to service function

Tags: php, laravel

I have a function in my laravel controller for login to a website, and I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to pass the two fields (email, and password)
into a function call `loginAttempt()`

Currently I have:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    //getting email and password form fields for validation
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    //Need to pass email and password into the loginAttempt() function

    $authService = new AuthService();
    $login = $authService->loginAttempt();
    dd($login);
}
```

I know I can use `$login = $authService->loginAttempt($arguments);` but the function I'm passing into needs the email and password as separate variables.

How can I pass them both into that `loginAttempt()` function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just grab the values from the input using `$request->input` as shown below

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    //getting email and password form fields for validation
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    //Need to pass email and password into the loginAttempt() function
    $email      = $request->input ('email');
    $password   = $request->input ('password');

    $authService = new AuthService();
    $login = $authService->loginAttempt($email, $password);
    dd($login);
}
```

Comment: No problem. Anytime. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

you can mulitple variable two ways function to function

first way
    passing each variable as separated

```
   $authService = new AuthService();
   $login = $authService->loginAttempt($request->email, $request->password);
```

second way 
create a `single dimension` array used like that

```
 $authService = new AuthService();
 $login = $authService->loginAttempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]);
```

and in your `AuthService` getting value by using key like that

```
$data['email'] or $data['password']
```